# Read a dataframe from csv/json/parquet depending on the argument given in spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

So, I'm reading a csv file into a dataframe in Spark (scala) using the following code:

```
val dataframe=spark.read
      .option("sep", args(0))
      .option("encoding","UTF-8")
      .schema(sch)
      .csv(args(1))
```

where `args(0)` is a runtime argument specifying the delimiter in my csv (comma, tab etc...), and `args(1)` is the S3 path from where the csv is read.

I want to generalize this input so that, depending on a third argument `args(2)`, I can read into my dataframe, either csv, or json, or parquet formats with the schema `sch`.

What would be the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.format` to specify the input file format (csv/json/parquet/etc.), and load the file using `.load`.

```
val dataframe = args(2) match {
    case "csv" => {spark.read
      .format(args(2))
      .option("sep", args(0))
      .option("encoding","UTF-8")
      .schema(sch)
      .load(args(1))
    } 
    case _ => {spark.read
      .format(args(2))
      .option("encoding","UTF-8")
      .schema(sch)
      .load(args(1))
    } 
}
```